# Creating an API to wrap an... API?

Tags: node.js, rest, api, abstract

This isn’t a specific issue question, but I’m trying to wrap my head around the concept of REST APIs and calling an API within your own API.

For example, if I develop an App called “BeesBees”, where users can buy bees, and I have a database of logins and passwords and obviously the bees, and how much each cost, I understand that I can used my own apps BeesBees API to get the list of bees (and if I make it open for other people, they can also use my GET /bees point to get, well, the bees)

But if I want to allow customers to buy the bees, and I don’t want to build a whole platform for doing so, so I integrate Stripe - could I have a POST /:users/charges/:priceOfBee API call that, in turn, called the Stripe API function somewhere somehow? For example, pointing to the URL of a Node.js project that will make the charge using Stripe’s Node.js SDK.

Or, in a case like this, would it be better to just implement the Stripe SDK for my device’s platform and make the charge using the device?

I have no code base so there’s nothing to pick apart, but I couldn’t think of anywhere else to ask, sorry y’all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly wrap APIs with other APIs, it's really just a form of composition, delegate to other services where it makes sense to do so.

Stripe integration might well be a good example of where it could make sense to follow this pattern. You certainly don't want to roll your own payment service.

Here's a trivial example of a local Express server making an API request:

```
const express = require("express");
const port = 3000;
const app = express();
const request = require('request');

app.get("/api/example", (req, res) => {
    // Make external REST request here...
    let options = {
        url: 'https://httpbin.org/get',
        qs: { parameter1: 42 },
        json: true
    }
    request(options, (err, response, body) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err.message);
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(body);
        }
    });
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('running at http://' + host + ':' + port)
});

console.log(`Serving at http://localhost:${port}`);
```